# How to plot a function showing discrete steps rather than continuous changes between samples in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wolfram-mathematica, primes

I want to plot prime counting function as a *step function* using *Python*. I have done this using *mathematica*, picture below -

[image: I want step wise graph like this one.]

**My python code**

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import sympy                        # for evaluating number of primes <= n 

def f(n):
    arr = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        arr.append(sympy.primepi(i))
        #print('For',i, 'value', arr[i-1])
    return arr

ar = f(100)

t1 = np.arange(1,101,1,dtype = int)
plt.plot(t1, ar ,'bo')           # instead of 'bo' what I need to use to make it like 1st picture?
plt.axis([0,110,0,25]) 
plt.show()
```

which produces

[image: this image.]

Can anyone tell me how to make this graph *stepwise* as it is in the first image?  and please share if there is any other good way to do this task which will be efficient.

**References**:

1. For more on prime counting function see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib has a step function implemented.

Just replace `plot` by `step`:

```
plt.step(t1, ar)
```

Note that you can control where the steps are rising via the kwarg `where` and it's values `{'pre', 'post', 'mid'}`

Comment: @taritgoswami b stands for color and o for shape. you can try 'r-'